# Working example of Material Design LinearProgress component

Tags: javascript, html, material-components-web

Attached are the pseudo-codes for an attempt to make a working prototype of a **Linear Progress** component.

#### HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@0.42.1/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
...
<div role="progressbar" class="mdc-linear-progress" id="my-progress-bar">
    <div class="mdc-linear-progress__buffering-dots"></div>
    <div class="mdc-linear-progress__buffer"></div>
    <div class="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__primary-bar">
        <span class="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__secondary-bar">
        <span class="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
const overallProgress = mdc.linearProgress.MDCLinearProgress.attachTo(document.getElementById('my-progress-bar'));
overallProgress.setProgress(0.5);
```

The aforementioned codes are intended to show a 50% progress. The prototype is not functional. Which part of it could have gone wrong? The below references are the best that I can get from the official reference documents.

#### References

1. [Linear Progress, Material Design for Web](https://material.io/develop/web/components/linear-progress/)
2. [Linear Progress Demo, Material Design for Web](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/linear-progress-indicator)

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR

Simply replace the JavaScript line `overallProgress.setProgress(0.5);`
into `overallProgress.progress=0.5;`

#### Details

I dig the [source-code of MDCLinearProgress](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-linear-progress/index.js#L38) and it turns out it was implemented to using [JavaScript function setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). The way function-setters work is by declaring in the class as methods but to actually set the value is by treating it like a property.

So instead of using `setProgress(value)`, replace it with `progress=value`.

Comment: And why are they writing use setProgress?